# Is there any diffrence between edit an utf-8 ini file with notepad or VS2010?

Tags: utf-8, ini, notepad

I have an application which needs to read an ini file as a predefine config. There are some Chinese characters in the ini file, so I chose utf-8 encoding. But when I edit the file with Windows notepad and change some of the Chinese characters, the application will flash close when I run it. But when I use VS2010 to change the same Chinese characters everything is OK.

Is there some difference between editing a utf-8 ini file with notepad and VS2010? I'd prefer to be able to use notepad to modify the ini file as it is the most convenient option and most users will already have access to it.

This is a reviewed version of previous question.

Comment: Apparently there is ...?

Comment: Then why can't I use notepad to edit the ini file? Thks @tripleee

Comment: A hex dump of the problematic characters would be a good starting point for troubleshooting.

Comment: @tripleee , I fond the problem, with notepad it will add BOM to the utf-8 ini file, after I use ultraedit remove the BOM, everything is OK. And it's OK with VS2010 because it will not add the BOM. Thks very much.

Comment: What do you mean by `notepad`? I am using Windows 7 and my notepad doesn't have utf-8 as an option. If you mean notepad++, then the correct encoding is `UTF-8 without bom`

Comment: @Esailija, there is an encoding dropdown list when you using "save as" in Windows notepad. And when the file is utf-8 encoding,no matter you using save or save as in Windows notepad, you will always get the BOM.

Comment: @DavidHao Oh it was there all this time and I didn't notice it. I mean, I checked the dropdown before making the first comment but I didn't notice it in the list back then :D